# Correct syntaxt to call object.draw_type = 'BOUNDS' as pie command?

Tags: scripting, interface, pie-menu

I would like to use `bpy.context.object.draw_type = 'BOUNDS'` as a pie operator like in the following line:

```
col.operator("object.draw_type", text="Object Solid", icon="MESH_CUBE").type='SOLID'
```

But I fail to figure out the correct way how to declare the type and get the error that draw_type has no attribute 'type' `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'`.

I checked the API and do not find any clues about how to declare this directly inside an operator.

> Maximum draw type to display object with in viewport
>
> BOUNDS Bounds, Draw the bounds of the object. WIRE Wire, Draw the
>   object as a wireframe. SOLID Solid, Draw the object as a solid (if
>   solid drawing is enabled in the viewport). TEXTURED Textured, Draw the
>   object with textures (if textures are enabled in the viewport).
>   Type: enum in [‘BOUNDS’, ‘WIRE’, ‘SOLID’, ‘TEXTURED’], default
>   ‘BOUNDS’
>
> draw_type Maximum draw type to display object with in viewport

Is this one of those commands where you have to define a class with the operator inside so you can all that via a pie instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read `wm.py` I promise this will be an eye-opener.

This has nothing to do with pies, pies are just specialized menu representations.  The property you are setting is an Enum ( a simple drop down in the UI is generally a representation of an Enum )

If you want to set the value of an Enum but don't want to present a dropdown, then you use `wm.context_set_enum`.

```
    if context.active_object:
        obj = context.active_object
        set_draw_type = layout.operator("wm.context_set_enum", text="Object Solid", icon="MESH_CUBE")
        set_draw_type.data_path = "object.draw_type"
        set_draw_type.value = 'BOUNDS'
```

wm.context_set_enum is defined in the class `WM_OT_context_set_enum`, 
which delegated the execute function to `execute_context_assign` (also found in `wm.py`)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I posted in an answer an example one can use to directly define the pie button.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case then you can write it this way as a pie and save the creating a custom operator to call.

```
f = pie.operator("wm.context_set_enum", icon='MESH_CUBE', text='Object Solid')
f.data_path='object.draw_type'
f.value = 'BOUNDS'
```